# Exception While Consume WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have tried to consume wcf service but I am getting error when I called the Binding Information from C# . Error is "no elements matching the key were found in the configuration" .
Can you help me out ?

I have checked and binding configuration name is same as in app.config file.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding("bindingconfig name");
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("endpoint address");
```

When I tried to call it throws an exception form WSHttpBinding object binding.

Comment: What does your (web/app).config file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the client proxy class to call the service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
Such as the below code segments.

```
ServiceReference1.TestServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.TestServiceClient();
try
{
    var result = client.GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
client.Close();
```

**Configuration(auto-generated).**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://10.157.13.69:16666/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" contract="ServiceReference1.ITestService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

the client proxy will use the default binding and endpoint address.
If the multiply service endpoints are generated in the configuration, we should specify the service endpoint used to communication by the construction function of the client proxy.

```
ServiceReference1.TestServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.TestServiceClient(“BasicHttpBinding_ITestService”);
```

Besides, we could also use ChannelFacotry to call the service, but they are essentially the same.

```
   Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.157.13.69:16666");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
       ChannelFactory<ICalculator> factory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(binding,new EndpointAddress(uri));
            ICalculator service = factory.CreateChannel();
            try
            {
                var result = service.Add(34.32, 2.34);
                Console.WriteLine(result);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        double Add(double a, double b);
    }
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.